what happens to provisional applications that are never converted to the non-provisional
After the 12 months, what will happen to the provisional application that is sitting on the USPTO's database if it is not converted to the non-provisional?
Will it be erased and deleted from their database?

What is usually meant by “convert” is to file a non-provisional that claims the benefit of one or more provisional applications. It is not a literal conversion.
As far as I know there is no mechanism to remove provisional applications from the USPTO database if they aren’t referenced by a non-provisional.
Note that there is now a way to petition for “restoration of priority” for a short while after the 12 months.
There is an obscure and extremely rarely  used procedure to literally convert an application from provisional to non-provisional. As a patent agent for ten years I used it once.

Can you really claim the benefits of more than one provisional? They would have different priority dates, correct? How is the different dates handled?
